# Angular 8 Peer Dependencies confusion

Tags: angular, npm

I'm working with Angular 8 and I continuously get npm warnings regarding angular/compiler-cli peer dependencies.

> npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@8.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@8.1.2 but 
>   none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

However, if I do a `npm install @angular/compiler@8.1.2`, npm continues to complain with the same message.

> @angular/compiler@^8.0.0 is installed package-json under dependencies and 
>   '@angular/compiler-cli@^8.1.2 and @angular/compiler@^8.1.2 are installed 
>   under devDependencies.

This doesn't make any sense to me.

Does anyone know how to produce error messages that will provide more information?

Or at least how to get this type of npm inconsistency resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First run the following code to automatically update in your project

```
ng update
```

Ng update is a command available in Angular CLI which is used to update your application and its dependencies.

if that's not working give it a try with the following command

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

> ```
> @angular/compiler@^8.0.0 is installed package-json under dependencies and '@angular/compiler-cli@^8.1.2 and
> @angular/compiler@^8.1.2 are installed under devDependencies.
> ```

There are two kinds of dependencies.

"dependencies": Packages required by your application in production.

"devDependencies": Packages that are only needed for local development and testing.

you will see these two in package.json in your project. The message tells that two different version for @angular/compilar is installed in these two dependencies

Answer (score 3):

Add below in package.json after or before `dependencies`:

```
"peerDependencies": {
   "@angular/compiler": "^8.1.2"
 }
```

After that run:
`npm install`.

**How peer dependencies solve this**
They tell npm

> I need this package, but I need the version that is part of the project, not some version private to my module.

When npm sees that your package is being installed into a project that does not have that dependency, or that has an incompatible version of it, it will warn the user during the installation process.

**When should you use peer dependencies?**

- When you are building a library to be used by other projects, and
- This library is using some other library, and
- You expect/need the user to work with that other library as well